# Python GTK AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'FlowBox'

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I am following [Python GTK3+ Tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to make some applications on Ubuntu. However, when I try to execute sample code given for [FLowBox](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html#flowbox), it results into following error:

`AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'FlowBox'`

I have GTK3 (v3.10.8) installed as well as Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4.0.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GtkFlowBox was introduced in GTK+ 3.12.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFlowBox.html#GtkFlowBox.description) You will either need to: a) find a way to upgrade your GTK+ packages (there might be a PPA for that; check the Ubuntu GNOME team's Launchpad), b) upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10, or c) refer to an older version of the tutorial (I don't know how to find that).